# ReflectionMethod::getReturnType()

Tags: php, laravel, reflection

I am facing an issue, I hope you guys are able to help me.

Basically I need to check a class method and get the return type class name.

Since PHP 7.0 is no longer possible cast (string)ReflectionMethod::getReturnType() to string, we get an error.

However the getReturnType() return an instance of ReflectionNamedType, with Laravel helper dd() I got the following:

```
ReflectionNamedType {
  name: "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo"
  allowsNull: false
  isBuiltin: false
}
```

The question is, since I cannot cast... how I can be able to get the name?

Thank you!

Comment: Cant you just use `$obj->name` to get `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo` from the `ReflectionNamedType` instance?

Comment: I've tried that and I got an error about missing class attribute "name"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionnamedtype.php. Use `getName()` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This is wired, I check the manual as well and I found that getName, but when I call $obj->getName() I got the undifine method exception... I will try agiain in a few minutes, and I will post here the code.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter actually this works, I was made a mistake, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that I use the method ReflectionNamedType::getName().

Answer (score 2):

`ReflectionMethod` is actually the wrong class to be using, in this case you want [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

Using Tinker I was able to get the name correctly with the following simple test:

```
// User.php
class User extends Model
{
    public function foos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Foo');
    }
}

// Foo.php
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}

$u = new User();
$r = new \ReflectionClass($u->foos());

echo $r->getName(); // Outputs "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany"
```